When click a row in a datagrid view , how data are autofill to relevant input fields in same form in C#?
I am doing a project on c#. I have created forms. In my userform, there are 3 input fields for user details as username, phone number and  password . when i click the add button it added details to the database and show in the grid view named "usersgv". the users details are viewed in the usersgv as one user detail(username , phone number and password) is stored in one row.
I want is when i click a row, the details in that selected row such as username , phone number and password should automatically filled to the relevant input fields. I used this code part for it.
    unameTb.Text = usersgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    uphoneTb.Text = usersgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    upassTb.Text = usersgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();   

when i run the program, when i click a row the details are not fill in to the relevant input fields.
How can I solve this problem?

You usually bind the Controls that need to present the content of data objects to a data source (the same data source or linked data sources, e.g., different Tables in a DataSet). This automates the presentation of the data. You didn't say whether some form of data binding is in place. If the DataGridView and the TextBoxes (I assume) don't share the same source of data, and you don't want to change that, in your code replace SelectedRows[0] with CurrentRow (which can be null, so test this condition beforehand. The Value of a Cell can also be null or DBNull)

I tried to test your problem and it works fine wit CurrentRow as suggested in the comments. Here my code in the CellClick event:
    private void usersgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(usersgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            unameTb.Text = usersgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            uphoneTb.Text = usersgv.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            upassTb.Text = usersgv.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

Heres how it should look:

Let me know if it works also on your machine.
